# UIWebView not detecting page breaks

Tags: html, ios, css, swift, uiwebview

I want to print document from webview.viewPrintformattor but page breaks are not working in UIwebview. please check below css.

```
<style type="text/css">
@media print {
.page-break {
    display: block;
    page-break-after: always;
}
@page {
    size: A4 portrait; /* can use also 'landscape' for orientation */
    margin: 0.5in;
    padding: 1em;
}

}
body {
    font-family: calibri, arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 15px;
    line-height: 1.5;
    color: #000000;
}
h1, h2, h3 {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
td {
    vertical-align: top;
}
.ar {
    direction: rtl;
    text-align: justify;
}
.page-break {
    display: block;
    page-break-after: always;
}
@page {
    size: A4 portrait; /* can use also 'landscape' for orientation */
    margin: 0.5in;
    padding: 1em;
}
</style>
```

and using below code for for pagebreak.

```
 <div class="page-break"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_print_pagebb.asp

Definition and Usage
The page-break-before property sets whether a page break should occur BEFORE a specified element.

Note: You cannot use this property on an empty `<div>` or on absolutely positioned elements.

Comment: I am using page-break-after, i added page-break-before for testing purpose only that i removed. but the issue is with UIwebview that is not detecting pagebreaks. any idea?

Comment: Both, before or after cannot be used on an empty div. Did you try doing something about that first?

Comment: i tried only these two(before and after). please suggest if you know how to break page.